# Namespacing version in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement some convention-based routing in my new .NET 5 API, based on how Rails does it. I'm putting all of my controllers in a different namespace for each version, for example Controllers/v1/MyController. The way this is done in the new .NET is different to how it was done in previous versions.

I'm looking for something as described in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/03/07/asp-net-web-api-using-namespaces-to-version-web-apis/), but even after looking through the asp.net docs and reading this [article on routing](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing), I am no closer to a solution.

My controllers currently look like this:

```
namespace SaleboatApi.Controllers.v1
{
    [Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
    public class MyController : Controller {
    ...
```

but I feel like if this is done right, I won't need the `Route` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Or.. rather than duplicating controllers per version have the version as a parameter that your controller acts on.

Less controllers = much easier to maintain

So your route would be more. something like:

`api/controller/action/version`

Psuedo, something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/myController")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{

    [Route("myAction/{version}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage MyAction(int version)
    {
         switch (version){
               case 1:
                 ...
               break;
               case 2:
                 ...
               break;
          }
          ......
    }   

}
```

Comment: This is how it is set up now, but that is just adding multiple actions to the same controller, the way I see it it's much over muchness...

Comment: I think there is a little misunderstanding - I will add a little more clarification